# SQLAlchemy: reflect table into explicitly created class

Tags: python, database, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have two schemas in the single PostgreSQL database and each schema contain table with the same name. For example: schema1.table, schema2.table.

I use SQLAlchemy for working with the database.

The first issue is that I can't reflect table from database specifying concrete schema into explicitly created class. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeferredReflection

Base = declarative_base()

class Table(DeferredReflection, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

## somehow specify schema for table

engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://localhost/postgres',
    isolation_level='READ UNCOMMITTED'
)

DeferredReflection.prepare(engine)

## do something using reflected table
```

The second issue is that I am looking for a way to bind one explicitly created class with tables from different schemas and use it as follows:

```
session = Session()
with schema_context('schema1'):
    data = session.query(Table).all()  # Table refers to schema1.table 
    ...

with schema_context('schema2'):
    data = session.query(Table).all() # Table refers to schema2.table
    ...
```

Is there some way to work around or solve described issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy `Table` object allows you to pass a [`schema` argument](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html?highlight=table#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.schema).

Using declarative, arguments are passed to the underlying `Table` object using `__table_args__`, as [documented here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration).

```
class MyTable(DeferredReflection, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema2'}
```

You must create separate tables for different schemas.